# How do I create a parent and add a child to it at the same time in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I keep getting a null reference when I try to create a collection and at the same time add a category to it. Did I forgot something? Or am I doing it all wrong?

```
private static void SamepleMethod(ICollectionRepository collectionRepo)
    {
        Collection collection = new Collection { CollectionName = "Collection" };

        Category category = new Category { Collection = collection, CategoryName = "Category" };

        category.SetCollection(collection);
        collection.AddCategory(category);

        collectionRepo.Save(collection);
    }
```

Collection:

```
public class Collection
{
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string CollectionName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public virtual void AddCategory(Category category)
    {
        Categories.Add(category);
        category.Collection = this;
    }
}
```

Category:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual Collection Collection { get; set; }

    public virtual void SetCollection(Collection collection)
    {
        Collection = collection;
        collection.Categories.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Collection.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               namespace="ACME.Model"
               assembly="ACME.Model">

<class name="Collection" table="Collections" >

<id name="Id" column="CollectionId" type="int" >
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>

<set name="Categories" inverse="true" cascade="all">
  <key column="CollectionId" />
  <one-to-many class="Category"></one-to-many>
</set>

<property name="CollectionName">
  <column name="CollectionName" sql-type="nvarchar(50)" />
</property>
```

Category.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               namespace="ACME.Model"
               assembly="ACME.Model">

<class name="Category" table="Categories" >

<id name="Id" column="CategoryId" type="int" >
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>

<many-to-one name="Collection"
             class="Collection"
             column="CollectionId"
             not-null="true" />

<property name="CategoryName">
  <column name="CategoryName" sql-type="nvarchar(50)" />
</property>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never initialized the `Categories` property in your `Collection` class, and therefore it remains at its default value of null...
You may want to initialize it to a new collection in the constructor.

Also, I've counted at least 3 different code lines where you associate a category with a collection.
I believe once is enough :) (I like it best in the `AddCategory` method, or in the ctor of `Category`).

Another small thing- hbm mapping files are a thing of the past; nowadays it's much more convenient (and less error-prone) to map in code.
You can do it either using the old extension [fluent nHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/), or the new official [mapping-by-code](http://notherdev.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html), which is also very good, but alas- lacking in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

(as sJhonny points out): Make sure that you initialize the Categories collection

Apart from that, I see other issues in your code (independent from your problem):

Only initialize the two references (from Collection to Category and vice versa) once.

Your code does:

```
 // set category.Collection
 Category category = new Category { Collection = collection ...
 // set collection agin
 category.SetCollection(collection);
     // within SetCollection, you add the category
     collection.Categories.Add(this);
 // and add the category agin
 collection.AddCategory(category);
```

It looks like the category can be put on several collections, which can have several categories. If this is the case, you should map them as `many-to-many`. If it is actually correct, don't mind.

You shouldn't use sql-type unless you are doing some special things. Simply map a string like this:

```
<property name="CategoryName" column="CategoryName" length="50" />
```

identity primary keys are discouraged because it gives you a bad performance.